# Creation of the list, addition of value of a column openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

I need to create a list with values in a column. If I use this code, Python reports a mistake:

```
for i in range(sheet.max_row):
rows = []
rows.append(sheet[f'A{i+1}'].value)
```

How to add all values of a column to the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
ListRows = []
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row):
bla=str(row)
rows1 = []
rows1.append(sheet['A' + bla].value)
rows1.append(sheet['B' + bla].value)
rows1.append(sheet['C' + bla].value)
rows1.append(sheet['D' + bla].value)
rows1.append(sheet['E' + bla].value)
rows1.append(sheet['F' + bla].value)
rows1.append(sheet['G' + bla].value)
rows1.append(sheet['H' + bla].value)
ListRows.append(rows1)
```